# How to receive from another URL in .NET CORE

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this url;
https://courier.yandex.ru/vrs/api/v1/result/mvrp/acfd99dd-14ca132a-2001a84c-9f29da24

I need to receive data from this url to wepapi. But my app starting with http://localhost
What kind of approach should i do. What should i do in controller and model. I am receiving data with postman. /acfd99dd-14ca132a-2001a84c-9f29da24 this part is id.
If anyone can help me and show the way should follow i would be glad.

Comment: In postman tool, are you making a GET or POST request to that courier url? In your asp.net code, in your controller class you could use `HttpClient` to make similar request to that url.

Comment: Yes i am making with courier url. I created a TestController and GetData function for that url. So, i need to create HttpClient in that function and return it ?

Comment: Post your code snippet and if any errors faced. It is upto you how you use the http response returned by that service.